# Partial UDP packet when recvfrom

Tags: python, sockets, udp

When I write TCP server, I usually use the following function as a robust `recv` function:

```
def _recv(socket, size: int):
    data        = []
    received    = 0
    while size != received:
        chunk, _ = socket.recv(size - received)
        data.append(chunk)
        received += len(chunk)
    return b''.join(data)
```

So if `recv` has returned less than `size` bytes, it will keep receiving until the full message is received.

Now I'm writing a UDP server, since UDP is a non-stream protocol, I cannot use `recvfrom` twice to read the same packet, so I use the code as follows:

```
def _recvfrom(socket, size: int):
    return socket.recvfrom(size)[0]
```

From `man 2 recvfrom`:

```
These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred.  
In the event of an error, errno is set to indicate the error.
```

We understand that `recvfrom` may return with partial data only (let's say the UDP packet is 100 bytes and `recvfrom` returned 50 bytes because of a software interrupt).

My question is, how can I distinguish between partial UDP packet and a full UDP packet received from `recv_from`? Or more specifically, how can one distinguish between `recvfrom` that ended because of a software interrupt and a successful one?

Comment: An interrupt can't cause a partial read. The only way you can read a partial packet is if the packet is larger than the buffer size.

Comment: Understood. So I guess python allocates large enough buffer. Can you please send me a reference to your statement?

Comment: I can't find a reference, but I know it's true. Datagrams only operate on complete messages. There's nothing sequential that can be interrupted.